# How to run unittest from a specfic module?

Tags: python

I'm new to python, I watched a video describing how to test code and in the video (and other resources) I've seen the command for running `python -m unittest test_utils.py` in the terminal.

However, when I run that command I get the following error:

`zsh: no such file or directory: /usr/local/bin/python3.8`

---

I'm running the `python -m ...` command from within the directory (as shown below)

Any thoughts on how to fix this so I can run my test scripts? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: It seems that you don´t have python installed as a global name. Check this out in case it helps https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-python-command-not-found/

Comment: if you are in linux, sometimes the global command is "python3" instead of python, so, try if "python3 -m unittest test_utils.py" works

Comment: Thank you for the help, I did some more digging around after taking a quick break. It seems like i setup my environment incorrectly. Thank you for the comments and links, the resource that helped me in particular was: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/python-version-on-mac-update/